# How is const std::wstring encoded and how to change to UTF-16

Tags: visual-c++, utf-8, c++17, utf-16, wstring

I created this minimum working C++ example snippet to compare bytes (by their hex representation) in a `std::string` and a `std::wstring` when defining a string with german non-ASCII characters in either type.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::wstring wstr = L"äöüß";
    std::string str = "äöüß";

    for ( unsigned char c : str ) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(c) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( wchar_t c : wstr ) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>(c) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this snippet is

```
c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc c3 9f 
00c3 00a4 00c3 00b6 00c3 00bc 00c3 0178
```

I ran this on a PC running itself **Windows 10 64-bit Pro**, compiling with **MSVC 2019 Community Edition** in Version 16.8.1, using build system **cmake** with following `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(wstring VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(wstring main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

I read, that `std::string`s are based on `char` type which is a single byte. I see that the output of my snippet indicates that `str` (the `std::string` variable) is **UTF-8** encoded. I read up, that Microsoft compilers use `wchar_t`s with 2 bytes to make up `std::wstring`s (instead of 4 byte `wchar_t`s by e.g. GNU gcc) and therefore would expect `wstr` (the `std::wstring` variable) to be (any kind of) **UTF-16** encoded. But I cannot figure out why the "ß" (latin sharp s) is encoded as `0x00c30178` I had expected `0x00df` instead. May somebody please tell me:

- Why this is happening?
- How may I end up with UTF-16 encoded `std::wstring`s (Big Endian would be fine, I do not mind a BOM)? Do I probably need to tell the compiler somehow?
- What kind of encoding is this?

### EDIT 1

changed title, as it did not fit the questions properly (and actually UTF-8 and UTF-16 are different encodings so the I my self new the answer already...)

### EDIT 2

forgot to mention: I use the `amd64` target of the mentioned compiler

### EDIT 3

if adding the `/utf-8` flag as pointed out in the comments by dxiv (see [his linked SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47704050/2195180)), I get the desired output

```
c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc c3 9f
00e4 00f6 00fc 00df
```

which looks like UTF-16-BE (no BOM) for me. As I had issues with the correct order of cmake commands this is my current `CmakeLists.txt` file. It is important to put the `add_compile_options` command before the `add_executable` command (I added the Notice for convenience)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(enctest VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

if (MSVC)
  message(NOTICE "compiling with MSVC")
  add_compile_options(/utf-8)
endif()

add_executable(enctest main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

I find the `if-endif` way more readable, than the generator-syntax one, but writing `add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")` instead would work as well.

**Note:** For Qt-Projects there is a nice switch for the `.pro` file (see [this Qt-Form post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76344/utf-8-characters-acting-strangely-in-windows-but-not-linux/9))

```
win32 {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /utf-8
}
```

Still the first part of my question is open: What encoding is `0x00c30178` for "ß" (latin sharp s)?

Comment: How does you *editor* save the file? Have you looked in e.g. a hex-editor at your own source file to see?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just did so, Notepad++ tells me that `main.cpp` is __UTF-8__ encoded, HxD shows me `C3 A4 C3 B6 C3 BC C3 9F` for both strings. I use Visual Studio Code with CMake Tools extension to create the project and edit it. But I get the same result using Qt Creator.

Comment: @Martin Is that UTF-8 with or without a BOM, and do you use [`/source-charset:utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=msvc-160)?

Comment: @dxiv as far as I know, UTF-8 does not contain BOMs as these are only required to inform about the endian-ness if character types are made up of more than 1 byte. Anyways the file does not start with a BOM, but a `0x23` which is "#". Regarding the `source-charset` not, if cmake does not set it automatically. I use the `CMakeLists.txt`. How may I set this with cmake?

Comment: @Martin VS uses the BOM to identify the encoding of the source file. Without a BOM, it "*assumes the source file is encoded using the current user code page*" which is not what you want here. See also [Possible to force CMake/MSVC to use UTF-8 encoding for source files without a BOM? C4819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690822/possible-to-force-cmake-msvc-to-use-utf-8-encoding-for-source-files-without-a-bo).

Comment: @dxiv thanks to point me to that SO thread. The answer there seems to be half the answer to my post, which actually the more important half. I'd still be interested in how `0x00c30178` comes up, but if you post your comment as an answer, I'd mark it as correct.

Comment: @Martin Posted as an answer, including the step-by-step `ß` --> `0xC3 0x9F` --> `U+00C3 U+0178`.

Comment: @Martin "*as far as I know, UTF-8 does not contain BOMs*" - a BOM is *discouraged* in UTF-8 but one is defined nonetheless. "*these are only required to inform about the endian-ness if character types are made up of more than 1 byte*" - A BOM does identify the *byte ordering* of UTF-16/UTF-32 data, but it ALSO differentiates between different UTFs. A UTF-32 BOM is different than a UTF-16 BOM, is different than a UTF-8 BOM, is different than a UTF-7 BOM, etc. A BOM is technically just the UTF-encoded form of the Unicode `U+FEFF` character, so you can determine the UTF used by looking at the BOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, the source `.cpp` file is UTF-8 encoded. Without a BOM, and without an explicit `/source-charset:utf-8` switch, the Visual C++ compiler defaults to assuming the source file is saved in the active codepage encoding. From the [Set Source Character Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=msvc-160) documentation:

> By default, Visual Studio detects a byte-order mark to determine if the source file is in an encoded Unicode format, for example, UTF-16 or UTF-8. If no byte-order mark is found, it assumes the source file is encoded using the current user code page, unless you specify a character set name or code page by using the /source-charset option.

The UTF-8 encoding of `äöüß` is `C3 A4 C3 B6 C3 BC C3 9F`, and therefore the line:

```
    std::wstring wstr = L"äöüß";
```

is seen by the compiler as:

```
    std::wstring wstr = L"\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6\xC3\xBC\xC3\x9F"`;
```

Assuming the active codepage to be the usual [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), the (extended) characters map as:

```
    win-1252    char    unicode

      \xC3       Ã       U+00C3
      \xA4       ¤       U+00A4
      \xB6       ¶       U+00B6
      \xBC       ¼       U+00BC
      \x9F       Ÿ       U+0178
```

Therefore `L"\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6\xC3\xBC\xC3\x9F"` gets translated to:

```
    std::wstring wstr = L"\u00C3\u00A4\u00C3\u00B6\u00C3\u00BC\u00C3\u0178"`;
```

To avoid such (mis)translation, Visual C++ needs to be told that the source file is encoded as UTF-8 by passing an explicit `/source-charset:utf-8` (or [`/utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-160)) compiler switch. For CMake based projects, this can be done using `add_compile_options` as shown at [Possible to force CMake/MSVC to use UTF-8 encoding for source files without a BOM? C4819](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690822/possible-to-force-cmake-msvc-to-use-utf-8-encoding-for-source-files-without-a-bo).

Answer (score 0):

> therefore would expect wstr (the std::wstring variable) to be (any kind of) UTF-16 encoded

`std::wstring` does not specify an encoding. It is a sequence of "wide characters", for some kind of wide characters (which are implementation defined).

There are conversion facets defined in the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) for converting to/from different encodings.

Comment: I read that as well, but still the compiler should create at least some valid encoding from which I can convert then my `wstring` to UTF-16? Otherwise defining hardcoded text in my program is less compatible than an external file in any valid encoding.

Comment: That's what "implementation defined" means - but the point I was making is that different compilers may do different things.